# How does a Segmentation Fault work under-the-hood?

Tags: shell, kernel, signals, segmentation-fault

I can't seem to find any information on this aside from "the CPU's MMU sends a signal" and "the kernel directs it to the offending program, terminating it".

I assumed that it probably sends the signal to the shell and the shell handles it by terminating the offending process and printing `"Segmentation fault"`. So I tested that assumption by writing an extremely minimal shell I call *crsh* (crap shell). This shell does not do anything except take user input and feed it to the `system()` method.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char cmdbuf[1000];
    while (1){
        printf("Crap Shell> ");
        fgets(cmdbuf, 1000, stdin);
        system(cmdbuf);
    }
}
```

So I ran this shell in a bare terminal (without `bash` running underneath). Then I proceeded to run a program that produces a segfault. If my assumptions were correct, this would either a) crash `crsh`, closing the xterm, b) not print `"Segmentation fault"`, or c) both.

```
braden@system ~/code/crsh/ $ xterm -e ./crsh
Crap Shell> ./segfault
Segmentation fault
Crap Shell> [still running]
```

Back to square one, I guess. I've just demonstrated that it's not the shell that does this, but the system underneath. How does "Segmentation fault" even get printed? "Who" is doing it? The kernel? Something else? How does the signal and all of its side effects propagate from the hardware to the eventual termination of the program?

Comment: When I first saw `crsh`, I thought it would be pronounced "crash." I'm not sure whether that's an equally fitting name.

Comment: This is a nice experiment... but you should know what `system()` does under the hood.  It turns out that `system()` will spawn a shell process!  So your shell process spawns another shell process and *that* shell process (probably `/bin/sh` or something like that) is the one that runs the program.  The way `/bin/sh` or `bash` works is by using `fork()` and `exec()` (or another function in the `execve()` family).

Comment: @DietrichEpp I had a feeling there was some kind of caveat like that with using `system()`. I hacked together a [rewrite of crsh](http://pastebin.com/mtgrc5Ri) to use execvp (which was difficult, but taught me a lot about how forking works), and re-did the experiment. Had some interesting results: 1. The shell still did not crash. 2. It did *not* print "Segmentation Fault." I know this is rather inconclusive since I could have made a silly error, but from what I'm seeing, it looks like the shell is responsible for printing "Segmentation Fault". Thoughts?

Comment: @BradenBest: Exactly.  Read the manual page `man 2 wait`, it will include the macros `WIFSIGNALED()` and `WTERMSIG()`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Just as you said! I tried adding a check for `(WIFSIGNALED(status) && WTERMSIG(status) == 11)` to have it print something goofy (`"YOU DUN GOOFED AND TRIGGERED A SEGFAULT"`). When I ran the `segfault` program from within `crsh`, it printed exactly that. Meanwhile, commands that exit normally don't produce the error message.

Comment: See also [What happens after a page fault?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231116/what-happens-after-a-page-fault)

Comment: Btw, you can emulate segfault by sending `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: @MatthewRock I know: `kill -11 <pid>`. But it's simpler to write a small program that segfaults than to: 1. write an infinite loop, 2. find the process with a tool like `ps`, 3. send `SIGSEGV`.

Comment: @BradenBest you have option to call signal from your program, using standard C library. That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Mmkay, but why do that when I can have the kernel do it for me? `char *p = 0; *p = 5;` is a lot simpler to write than including a header like `<sys/signal.h>` and using library functions to trigger a signal.

Comment: I have to say that by it's very nature, it doesn't work.

Comment: @BigHomie what does "it" refer to?

Comment: It was a pun, ya know b/c the program that caused the seg fault is no longer working :'(

Comment: @BigHomie ah, it "doesn't work" in the sense that a thwarted bank robbery "doesn't work". Gotcha.

Comment: Try `popen()` rather than `system()`

Answer (score 265, accepted):

All modern CPUs have the capacity to [*interrupt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) the currently-executing machine instruction. They save enough state (usually, but not always, on the stack) to make it possible to *resume* execution later, as if nothing had happened (the interrupted instruction will be restarted from scratch, usually). Then they start executing an *interrupt handler*, which is just more machine code, but placed at a special location so the CPU knows where it is in advance. Interrupt handlers are always part of the *kernel* of the operating system: the component that runs with the greatest privilege and is responsible for supervising execution of all the other components.<sup>1,2</sup>

Interrupts can be *synchronous*, meaning that they are triggered by the CPU itself as a direct response to something the currently-executing instruction did, or *asynchronous*, meaning that they happen at an unpredictable time because of an external event, like data arriving on the network port. Some people reserve the term "interrupt" for asynchronous interrupts, and call synchronous interrupts "traps", "faults", or "exceptions" instead, but those words all have other meanings so I'm going to stick with "synchronous interrupt".

Now, most modern operating systems have a notion of *processes*. At its most basic, this is a mechanism whereby the computer can run more than one program at the same time, but it is also a key aspect of how operating systems configure [*memory protection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection), which is is a feature of most (but, alas, still not *all*) modern CPUs. It goes along with [*virtual memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), which is the ability to alter the mapping between memory addresses and actual locations in RAM. Memory protection allows the operating system to give each process its own private chunk of RAM, that only it can access. It also allows the operating system (acting on behalf of some process) to designate regions of RAM as read-only, executable, shared among a group of cooperating processes, etc. There will also be a chunk of memory that is only accessible by the kernel.<sup>3</sup>

As long as each process accesses memory only in the ways that the CPU is configured to allow, memory protection is invisible. When a process breaks the rules, the CPU will generate a synchronous interrupt, asking the kernel to sort things out. It regularly happens that the process didn't *really* break the rules, only the kernel needs to do some work before the process can be allowed to continue. For instance, if a page of a process's memory needs to be "evicted" to the swap file in order to free up space in RAM for something else, the kernel will mark that page inaccessible. The next time the process tries to use it, the CPU will generate a memory-protection interrupt; the kernel will retrieve the page from swap, put it back where it was, mark it accessible again, and resume execution.

But suppose that the process really did break the rules. It tried to access a page that has never had any RAM mapped to it, or it tried to execute a page that is marked as not containing machine code, or whatever. The family of operating systems generally known as "Unix" all use *signals* to deal with this situation.<sup>4</sup> Signals are similar to interrupts, but they are generated by the kernel and fielded by processes, rather than being generated by the hardware and fielded by the kernel. Processes can define *signal handlers* in their own code, and tell the kernel where they are. Those signal handlers will then execute, interrupting the normal flow of control, when necessary.  Signals all have a number and two names, one of which is a cryptic acronym and the other a slightly less cryptic phrase.  The signal that's generated when the a process breaks the memory-protection rules is (by convention) number 11, and its names are `SIGSEGV` and "Segmentation fault".<sup>5,6</sup>

An important difference between signals and interrupts is that there is a *default behavior* for every signal. If the operating system fails to define handlers for all interrupts, that is a bug in the OS, and the entire computer will crash when the CPU tries to invoke a missing handler. But processes are under no obligation to define signal handlers for all signals. If the kernel generates a signal for a process, and that signal has been left at its default behavior, the kernel will just go ahead and do whatever the default is and not bother the process. Most signals' default behaviors are either "do nothing" or "terminate this process and maybe also produce a core dump." `SIGSEGV` is one of the latter.

So, to recap, we have a process that broke the memory-protection rules. The CPU suspended the process and generated a synchronous interrupt. The kernel fielded that interrupt and generated a `SIGSEGV` signal for the process. Let's assume the process did *not* set up a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, so the kernel carries out the default behavior, which is to terminate the process. This has all the same effects as the [`_exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) system call: open files are closed, memory is deallocated, etc.

Up till this point nothing has printed out any messages that a human can see, and the shell (or, more generally, the *parent process* of the process that just got terminated) has not been involved at all. `SIGSEGV` goes to the process that broke the rules, *not* its parent. The *next* step in the sequence, though, is to notify the parent process that its child has been terminated. This can happen in several different ways, of which the simplest is when the parent is already waiting for this notification, using one of the [`wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wait) system calls (`wait`, `waitpid`, `wait4`, etc). In that case, the kernel will just cause that system call to return, and supply the parent process with a code number called an *exit status*.<sup>7</sup> The exit status informs the parent *why* the child process was terminated; in this case, it will learn that the child was terminated due to the default behavior of a `SIGSEGV` signal.

The parent process may then report the event to a human by printing a message; shell programs almost always do this. Your `crsh` doesn't include code to do that, but it happens anyway, because the C library routine [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) runs a full-featured shell, `/bin/sh`, "under the hood". `crsh` is the *grandparent* in this scenario; the parent-process notification is fielded by `/bin/sh`, which prints its usual message. Then `/bin/sh` itself exits, since it has nothing more to do, and the C library's implementation of `system` receives *that* exit notification. You can see that exit notification in your code, by inspecting the return value of `system`; but it won't tell you that the grandchild process died on a segfault, because that was consumed by the intermediate shell process.

---

#### Footnotes

1. Some operating systems don't implement *device drivers* as part of the kernel; however, all interrupt handlers still have to be part of the kernel, and so does the code that configures memory protection, because the hardware doesn't allow anything *but* the kernel to do these things.
2. There may be a program called a "hypervisor" or "virtual machine manager" that is even more privileged than the kernel, but for purposes of this answer it can be considered part of the *hardware*.
3. The kernel is a *program*, but it is *not* a process; it is more like a library. All processes execute parts of the kernel's code, from time to time, in addition to their own code. There may be a number of "kernel threads" that *only* execute kernel code, but they do not concern us here.
4. The one and only OS you are likely to have to deal with anymore that *can't* be considered an implementation of Unix is, of course, Windows. It does not use signals in this situation. (Indeed, it does not *have* signals; on Windows the `<signal.h>` interface is completely faked by the C library.) It uses something called "[structured exception handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" instead.
5. Some memory-protection violations generate `SIGBUS` ("Bus error") instead of `SIGSEGV`. The line between the two is underspecified and varies from system to system.  If you've written a program that defines a handler for `SIGSEGV`, it is probably a good idea to define the same handler for `SIGBUS`.
6. "Segmentation fault" was the name of the interrupt generated for memory-protection violations by one of the computers that ran the [original Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix), probably the [PDP-11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11).  "[Segmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation)" is a *type* of memory protection, but nowadays the term "segmentation *fault*" refers generically to any sort of memory protection violation.
7. All the *other* ways the parent process might be notified of a child having terminated, end up with the parent calling `wait` and receiving an exit status.  It's just that something else happens first.

Comment: @zvol: ad 2) I don't think it's right to say that CPU knows anything about processes. You should say that it invokes an interrupt handler, which transfers control.

Comment: @user323094 Modern multicore CPUs do actually know quite a bit about processes; enough so that, in this situation, they can suspend only the thread of execution that triggered the memory-protection fault. Also, I was trying not to get into low-level details. From the user-space programmer's perspective, the most important thing to understand about step 2 is that it's the *hardware* that detects violations of memory protection; less so the precise division of labor between the hardware, the firmware, and the operating system when it comes to identifying the "offending process".

Comment: Another subtlety that might confusing a naive reader is *"The kernel sends the offending process a SIGSEGV signal."* which uses the usual jargon, but actually means that the kernel tells *itself* to deal with signal foo on process bar (i.e. the userland code doesn't get involved unless there is a signal handler installed, a question which is resolved by the kernel). I sometime prefer *"raises a SIGSEGV signal on the process"* for that reason.

Comment: The significant difference between SIGBUS (bus error) and SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) is this: SIGSEGV occurs when the CPU *knows* you shouldn't access an address (and so it doesn't make any external memory bus request). SIGBUS occurs when the CPU only finds out about the addressing problem once it has put your request on its external address bus. For example, asking for a physical address to which nothing on the bus responds, or asking to read data on a mis-aligned boundary (which would require two physical requests to get instead of one)

Comment: @StuartCaie You're describing the behavior of _interrupts_; indeed, many CPUs make the distinction you outline (although some do not, and the line between the two varies). The _signals_ SIGSEGV and SIGBUS, however, are _not_ reliably mapped to those two CPU-level conditions. The only condition where POSIX requires SIGBUS rather than SIGSEGV is when you `mmap` a file into a memory region that is bigger than the file, and then access "whole pages" beyond the end of the file. (POSIX is otherwise quite vague about when SIGSEGV/SIGBUS/SIGILL/etc happen.)

Comment: @dmckee Please let me know what you think of the rewrite.

Answer (score 43):

The shell does indeed have something to do with that message, and `crsh` indirectly calls a shell, which is probably `bash`.

I wrote a small C program that always seg faults:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
        int *i = NULL;

        *i = 12;

        return 0;
}
```

When I run it from my default shell, `zsh`, I get this:

```
4 % ./segv
zsh: 13512 segmentation fault  ./segv
```

When I run it from `bash`, I get what you noted in your question:

```
bediger@flq123:csrc % ./segv
Segmentation fault
```

I was going to write a signal handler in my code, then I realized that the `system()` library call used by `crsh` exec's a shell, `/bin/sh` according to `man 3 system`.  That `/bin/sh` is almost certainly printing out "Segmentation fault", since `crsh` certainly isn't.

If you re-write `crsh` to use the `execve()` system call to run the program, you will not see the "Segmentation fault" string. It comes from the shell invoked by `system()`.

Comment: I was just discussing this with Dietrich Epp. I [hacked together](http://pastebin.com/mtgrc5Ri) a version of crsh that uses `execvp` and did the test again to find that while the shell still doesn't crash (meaning SIGSEGV is never sent to the shell), it does *not* print "Segmentation Fault". Nothing is printed at all. This seems to indicate that the shell detects when its child processes get killed and is responsible for printing "Segmentation fault" (or some variant thereof).

Comment: @BradenBest - I did the same thing, my code is sloppier than your code. I got no message at all, and my even crappier shell doesn't print a thing. I used `waitpid()` on each fork/exec, and it returns a different value for processes that have a segmentation fault, than processes that exit with 0 status.

Answer (score 21):

> I can't seem to find any information on this aside from "the CPU's MMU sends a signal" and "the kernel directs it to the offending program, terminating it".

This is a bit of a garbled summary. The Unix signal mechanism is entirely different from the CPU-specific events that start the process.

In general, when a bad address is accessed (or written to a read-only area, attempt to execute a non-executable section, etc.), the CPU will generate some CPU-specific event (on traditional non-VM architectures this was called a segmentation violation, since each "segment" (traditionally, the read-only executable "text", the writable and variable-length "data", and the stack traditionally at the opposite end of memory) had a fixed range of addresses - on a modern architecture it's more likely to be a page fault [for unmapped memory] or an access violation [for read, write, and execute permission issues], and I'll focus on this for the rest of the answer).

Now, at this point, the kernel can do several things. Page faults are also generated for memory that is valid but not loaded (e.g. swapped out, or in a mmapped file, etc.), and in this case the kernel will map the memory and then restart the user program from the instruction that caused the error. Otherwise, it sends a signal. This doesn't exactly "direct [the original event] to the offending program", since the process for installing a signal handler is different and mostly architecture-independent, vs. if the program were expected to simulate installing an interrupt handler.

If the user program has a signal handler installed, this means creating a stack frame and setting the user program's execution position to the signal handler. The same is done for all signals, but in the case of a segmentation violation things are generally arranged so that if the signal handler returns it will restart the instruction that caused the error. The user program may have fixed the error, e.g. by mapping memory to the offending address - it's architecture-dependent whether this is possible). The signal handler can also jump to a different location in the program (typically via [longjmp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h) or by throwing an exception), to abort whatever operation caused the bad memory access.

If the user program does not have a signal handler installed, it is simply terminated. On some architectures, if the signal is ignored it may restart the instruction over and over, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: +1, only answer that adds anything to the accepted one.  Nice description of the "segmentation" history.  Fun fact: x86 actually still has [segment limits](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segment_Limits) in 32bit protected mode (with or without paging (virtual memory) enabled), so instructions that access memory can generate `#PF(fault-code)` (page fault) or `#GP(0)` ("If a memory operand effective address is outside the CS, DS, ES, FS, or GS segment limit.").  64bit mode drops segment limit checks, since OSes just used paging instead, and a flat memory model for user-space.

Comment: Actually, I believe most OSes on x86 use segmented pagination: a bunch of big segments inside a flat, paged address space. This is how you protect and map kernel memory into each address space: rings (protection levels) are linked to segments, not pages

Comment: Also, on NT (but I would love to know if on most Unixes is the same!) "segmentation fault" could happen quite often: there is a 64k protected segment at the beginning of the user space, so dereferencing a NULL pointer raises a (proper?) segmentation fault

Comment: @LorenzoDematté Yes, all-or-nearly-all modern Unixes will leave a chunk of permanently unmapped addresses at the beginning of the address space in order to catch NULL dereferences.  It can be quite large -- on 64-bit systems, in fact, it might be four *gigabytes*, so that accidental truncation of pointers to 32 bits will be caught promptly.  However, *segmentation* in the strict x86 sense is barely used at all; there is one flat segment for user space and one for the kernel, and maybe a couple for special tricks like getting some use out of FS and GS.

Comment: @LorenzoDematté NT uses exceptions rather than signals; in this case STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

Comment: @zwol they are two important segments anyway :)
Do you know if they still exists for x64?

Comment: @LorenzoDematté Yes, they do.

Answer (score 19):

A segmentation fault is an access to a memory address that isn't allowed (not part of the process, or trying to write read-only data, or execute non-executable data, ...). This is caught by the MMU (Memory Management Unit, today part of the CPU), causing an interrupt. The interrupt is handled by the kernel, which sends a `SIGSEGFAULT` signal (see `signal(2)` for instance) to the offending process. The default handler for this signal dumps core (see `core(5)`) and terminates the process.

The shell has absolutely no hand in this.

Comment: It's also worth noting that SIGSEGV *can* be handled/ignored. So it's possible to write a program that doesn't get terminated by it. The Java Virtual Machine is one notable example that uses SIGSEGV internally for different purposes, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731784/a-lot-of-sigsegv-while-straceing-java-process

Comment: Likewise, on Windows, .NET doesn't bother adding null pointer checks in most cases - it just catches access violations (equivalent to segfaults).