# How is Mono magical?

Tags: linux, executable, cross-compilation, mono

I'm learning C#, so I made a little C# program that says `Hello, World!`, then compiled it with `mono-csc` and ran it with `mono`:

```
$ mono-csc Hello.cs
$ mono Hello.exe
Hello, World!
```

I noticed that when I hit `TAB` in `bash`, `Hello.exe` was marked executable. Indeed, it runs by just a shell loading the filename!

`Hello.exe` is *not* an ELF file with a funny file extension:

```
$ readelf -a Hello.exe
readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
$ xxd Hello.exe | head -n1
00000000: 4d5a 9000 0300 0000 0400 0000 ffff 0000  MZ..............
```

`MZ` means it's a Microsoft Windows statically linked executable. Drop it onto a Windows box, and it will (should) run.

I have `wine` installed, but `wine`, being a compatibility layer for Windows apps, takes about 5x as long to run `Hello.exe` as `mono` and executing it directly do, so it's not `wine` that runs it.

I'm assuming there's some `mono` kernel module installed with `mono` that intercepts the `exec` syscall/s, or catches binaries that begin with `4D 5A`, but `lsmod | grep mono` and friends return an error.

What's going on here, and how does the kernel know that *this* executable is special?

---

Just for proof it's not *my* shell working magic, I used [the Crap Shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257598) (aka `sh`) to run it and it still runs natively.

---

Here's the program in full, since a commenter was curious:

```csharp
using System;

class Hello {
  /// <summary>
  ///   The main entry point for the application
  /// </summary>
  [STAThread]
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    System.Console.Write("Hello, World!\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: While you got answer, But I am little bit confused, If you run the commands like `php hello.php` or `python hello.py` or `perl hello.pl` or in case of compiled language like java `java hello` they would also run as their are no executable there but a program read and execute file. However if you run `./hello.exe` instead of `mono hello.exe` the I found your question and accepted answer more reasonable (which in case definitely use binfmt-support.

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj I'm not sure I understand what you're saying but I was just surprised that a Windows executable runs"natively" on a Linux box.

Comment: Actually what I was saying that any code file (or compiled file ) can be executed via its program in format `program codefile`, in your case program is mono, while my examples includes php, python, perl and  java. I suspect if mono allow extension to other than .exe file still executed via code. It should not depend at all on windows as finally this is execute a compiled code. However if your source file have some dependent code like windows only APIs then obviously you must need wine for running that exe file.

Comment: However I checkout  this code and able to run by using `./hello.exe` which is without defining program and require it be executable, So there must be role of binfmt_misc to mark it as executable by mono.

Comment: Part of the wonderful irony of this is that  `/etc/magic` or `/usr/share/file/magic` (or similar magical location) is the file that contains the information necessary to be able to do this.

Comment: @MichaelT I thought `magic` was just identifying native file types like media, I never realised it did interesting stuff like this :)

Comment: @cat its a *very* interesting file (if I was to have a favorite file, it would probably be my first choice). It has the information for identifying all sorts of files. But you need to identify what the file is first before you can figure out how to run it. That's what file and its magic does.  A similar thing - [Java Binary Kernel Support for Linux](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/java.txt) from awhile back so you could do `$ foo.jar` rather than `$ java -jar foo.jar` - similar to what is done for mono.

Comment: Just to clarify, `binfmt_misc` doesn't use `magic`, but as long as the magic bytes are within the first 128 you can use the information given in the magic files to write a `binfmt_misc` descriptor. If you want to find out more about magic files, look at `libmagic`.

Comment: BTW, even ELF files usually specify their own interpreter in a way... that interpreter being the system's dynamic linker.

Comment: Is Crap Shell a thing now?

Comment: @asmeurer ya it is (8

Answer (score 205, accepted):

This is [binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) in action: it allows the kernel to be told how to run binaries it doesn't know about. Look at the contents of `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc`; among the files you see there, one should explain how to run Mono binaries:

```
enabled
interpreter /usr/lib/binfmt-support/run-detectors
flags:
offset 0
magic 4d5a
```

(on a Debian system). This tells the kernel that binaries starting with `MZ` (`4d5a`) should be given to `run-detectors`. The latter figures out whether to use Mono or Wine to run the binary.

Binary types can be added, removed, enabled and disabled at any time; see the documentation above for details (the semantics are surprising, the virtual filesystem used here doesn't behave entirely like a standard filesystem). `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status` gives the global status, and each binary "descriptor" shows its individual status. Another way of disabling `binfmt_misc` is to unload its kernel module, if it's built as a module; this also means it's possible to blacklist it to avoid it entirely.

This feature allows new binary types to be supported, such as MZ executables (which include Windows PE and PE+ binaries, but also DOS and OS/2 binaries!), Java JAR files... It also allows known binary types to be supported on new architectures, typically using Qemu; thus, with the appropriate libraries, you can transparently run ARM Linux binaries on an Intel processor!

Your question stemmed from cross-compilation, albeit in the .NET sense, and that brings up a caveat with `binfmt_misc`: some configuration scripts misbehave when you try to cross-compile on a system which can run the cross-compiled binaries. Typically, detecting cross-compilation involves building a binary and attempting to run it; if it runs, you're not cross-compiling, if it doesn't, you are (or your compiler's broken). `autoconf` scripts can usually be fixed in this case by explicitly specifying the build and host architectures, but sometimes you'll have to disable `binfmt_misc` temporarily...

Comment: To those who are curious about /proc, you may be interested in [How does /proc/* work?](http://superuser.com/q/619955/53590) on [su].