# Why is pstree showing the name of my script instead of the name of the shell that is interpreting it?

Tags: shell, process

I have written a simple shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 90
```

After running this shell I run `pstree` in a separate shell to see the process tree structure.

Here is what I see

```
-gnome-terminal-+-bash---sleepy.sh---sleep
```

I was expecting this to be like

```
-gnome-terminal-+-bash---bash---sleep
```

Why is a shell script being represented as a process by pstree? The `ps` command correctly shows the command being executed as

```
10150  8771  0 08:13 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./sleepy.sh
```

Here the process is bash and sleepy.sh is its argument (this makes sense to me). In my view a process has to be an Executable Linkable Format binary (ELF). Bash is an ELF executable but a shell script is not and hence I think `pstree` should not be showing it as such?

Comment: Because it's a process.

Comment: That's not what the questioner is asking, Ipor Sircer.  The title is badly phrased.  It would be better to read something along the lines of _Why is pstree showing the name of my script instead of the name of the shell that is interpreting it?_

Comment: Did you run this script by name, or did you run this script using 'bash sleepy.sh'?

Answer (score 6):

`pstree` [retrieves the process name from `/proc/<pid>/stat`](https://gitlab.com/psmisc/psmisc/blob/master/src/pstree.c#L889). This is whatever was given to the kernel *via* [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)'s first parameter; see [`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [What exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268766/86440) for details. You'll see from the latter that the kernel *can* run shell scripts directly (and many other "binaries" — see [How is Mono magical?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/86440)), but the shell also steps in in some cases.

Thus, if you run

```
./sleepy.sh
```

with a shebang line at the start of the script, you'll see `sleepy.sh` in `pstree`'s output because that's what the shell asks the kernel to run. If instead you run

```
sh ./sleepy.sh
```

you'll see `sh` in `pstree`'s output.

`ps -f` or `ps u` (and `pstree -a`) read `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` instead to retrieve the *command line*, which is different — it's the `argv` parameter given to the `execve` system call. When running a shell script with a shebang, this is changed to include the shebang, which is no doubt why in your case `ps` shows

```
/bin/bash ./sleepy.sh
```

(see [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) for lots more on this).