# Writing C# in Debian

Tags: debian, software-installation, programming, c#

I want to learn C# on a Debian system.

What do I have to install?

Is there something like an interactive prompt where I can try running snippets of code?

I have to learn C# and I have a dual boot computer, but don't feel like powering off Linux and booting Windows just for learning C#.

Comment: Hey, why all the negative votes? Is that because it's a question about a MS technology?

Comment: I have edited it not to look like a request for learning materials (which is what it's getting close votes for).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What do I have to install?

```
apt install mono-mcs
```

and optionally

```
apt install monodevelop
```

if you want something more like an IDE.

`mcs` is the compiler. You can run the compiled program with `mono prog.exe` (or as `./prog.exe` with [`binfmt_misc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259376/73093) support enabled, which I believe Debian will do by default).

> Is there something like a prompt where I can try running snippets of code?

```
apt install mono-csharp-shell
```

and then

```
$ csharp
Mono C# Shell, type "help;" for help

Enter statements below.
csharp> Console.WriteLine("Hello world!")
Hello world!
csharp>
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the previous answer, there's also the .NET Core SDK, which is has a faster and cleaner implementation of the .NET framework(albeit it's somewhat imcomplete, being a Core CLR. Still really reliable, though). If you don't need C# for WinForms, UWP and WPF development, I really recommend checking it out. By now, most libraries should be supporting .NET Core. Download link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

As for the IDE, there's VS Code, which is the one I'm currently using, and JetBrains Rider. MonoDevelop does have an addon for NET Core support, but I heard it's lacking features(especially on the debug department).